# Presentation Display is null Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, hdmi, external-display

I need to enable sharing content on a secondary screen via a HDMI port on android, and hence am using the Presentation api provided in 4.2.

But while running the sample code provided from [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicMediaRouter/index.html).
The hdmi connection is detected and even mirroring of the screen works fine but not the presentation display[if you look at the toast, Presentation display is null], can anyone explain what is happening here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can happen the device you're using doesn't support displaying a presentation on any route.
Have you tried to run your code code while using the "Simulate secondary displays" functionality available in developer settings ?